# Gateway Filter: connection prematurely closed

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

With connecting the `DataBuffer`-flux to the filter chain ..

```java
@Component
public class GlobalPayloadFilter implements GlobalFilter {
  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
    HttpMethod method = exchange.getRequest().getMethod();
    if (method != HttpMethod.POST) {
      return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
    return exchange.getRequest().getBody().doOnNext(buffer -> {
      /* access buffer */
    }).then(chain.filter(exchange));
  }
}
```

.. the request will time out. The log then states, that ..

```
The connection observed an error

reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response
```

It looks like this type of connection leads to a blocking thread.

Does anyone may help?

Comment: One thing that could be bad : you access the request body, then pass the same request on the filter chain. I think it is invalid. If you access request body, the request is then consumed and cannot be consumed back by the filter chain. I think that you might have to create some sort of "buffered" request yourself, so you can have a request that can be consumed twice. Note, I have not searched about it, so I cannot give more hints about the problem at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There's an alternative way to access the cached body using the `ServerWebExchangeUtils.cacheRequestBodyAndRequest()`-approach. This should avoid a possible unwanted consumption. But even this approach will lead to the same faulty behaviour.

Comment: we also went into strange occurance of "Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response". now we think that blocking code inside filters can cause this problem. will be back after improvements